failing to create a deep copy of a vector while not affecting original vector
i have a Player class which has a Vector that stores Hero objects, to get the vector, use this method:
public class Player {
    private String playerID;
    private String playerName;
    private Vector<Hero> heroes;

    public Player(String playerID, String playerName) {
        this.playerID = playerID;
        this.playerName = playerName;
        heroes = new Vector<>(2, 1);
    }

// other getters and setters
public void addHero(Hero hero) {
        heroes.add(hero);
    }

public Vector<Hero> getHeroes() {
        return new Vector<>(heroes);
    }
}

everytime i have done an action (create player, add hero etc.), i create a Save (another class). inside a Save object, it stores a List of Player objects and to do that i created a Copier class which attempts to create a deep copy of all the Players and the Vector of each Player object as shown below:
package memento;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import heroes.*;
import players.*;

public class Copier {
    public Copier(){}

    public List<Player> getDeepCopy(List<Player> ogList){
        List<Player> copyPlayerList = new ArrayList<>();
        // loop each player
        for (Player player : ogList){
            try{
                Player copyPlayer = createPlayerCopy(player);
                // get player's heroes
                Vector<Hero> playerHero = new Vector<>();
                playerHero.addAll(player.getHeroes());
                // loop heroes and put into copy vector
                for (Hero hero : playerHero){
                    Hero copyHero = createHeroCopy(hero);
                    // this is also adding another copy to og list why?
                    copyPlayer.addHero(copyHero);
                }
                copyPlayerList.add(copyPlayer);
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Failed to copy");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return copyPlayerList;
    }

    private Player createPlayerCopy(Player player) throws Exception {
        Class<?> clazz = player.getClass();
        // Create a new instance using the constructor that matches the Player class
        Player copyPlayer = (Player) clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, String.class).newInstance(player.getPlayerID(), player.getPlayerName());
    
        // If the subclass has additional properties, copy them using reflection
        for (java.lang.reflect.Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (!field.getName().equals("playerID") && !field.getName().equals("playerName")) {
                field.setAccessible(true); // Make private fields accessible
                field.set(copyPlayer, field.get(player)); // Copy value from original to copy
            }
        }
    
        return copyPlayer;
    }

    private Hero createHeroCopy(Hero hero) throws Exception {
        Class<?> clazz = hero.getClass();
        // Create a new instance using the constructor that matches the Hero class
        Hero copyHero = (Hero) clazz.getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, String.class).newInstance(hero.getHeroID(), hero.getHeroName());
    
        // Set the base stats from the original hero to the copy
        copyHero.setDamage(hero.getDamage());
        copyHero.setHP(hero.getHP());
    
        // If the subclass has additional properties, copy them using reflection
        for (java.lang.reflect.Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (!field.getName().equals("heroID") && !field.getName().equals("heroName") && !field.getName().equals("hp") && !field.getName().equals("damage")) {
                field.setAccessible(true); // Make private fields accessible
                field.set(copyHero, field.get(hero)); // Copy value from original to copy
            }
        }
    
        return copyHero;
    }
}

however, this line ,copyPlayer.addHero(copyHero);, somehow also adds the Hero copy to the original Vector
without changing any code in both Player and Hero class, how can i achieve it?
current outcome:
when showing a player's stats, it shows the player's name, id and all the heroes (if only created 1 hero, somehow shows 2 of the same heroes, same name, id and class)
desired outcome:
when showing a player's stats, it shows the player's name, id and all the heroes (if only created 1 hero, then show the only hero)
better representation of outcomes:
current:
Showing player info for test1
ID: p01
Name: test1
Heroes:
debugging in player class
Hero:   hero1 (h02)
Class:  Warlock
HP:     150
Damage: 200
MP:     250

debugging in player class
Hero:   hero1 (h02)
Class:  Warlock
HP:     150
Damage: 200
MP:     250

desired:
Showing player info for test1
ID: p01
Name: test1
Heroes:
debugging in player class
Hero:   hero1 (h02)
Class:  Warlock
HP:     150
Damage: 200
MP:     250


If you don't want duplicates, don't use a Vector but use a Set, and also make sure your classes always implement the equals method (and, if you use hashing containers, which you likely will because HashSet is the go-to Set implementation, hashCode as well).

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i would love to not use Vector, but we are not allowed to change anything in the player and hero classes, think of it as view only but we can create an object in main or somewhere else

Cool: put that information in your post (and make that part of the very first paragraph explaining your situation). Asking about homework is fine but be explicit about what you can and cannot do, because homework solutions are usually terrible solutions for people looking for real solutions and ending up finding your question.

The problem is that when you copy the Player object, the Vector of Hero objects still points to the same heroes as the original Player. So when you add the copied heroes, they end up showing up twice.
To fix this, just create a new Vector for each player's heroes when you're copying, so that the new Player gets its own heroes.

on the line:
Player copyPlayer = (Player) clazz.getDeclaredConstructor( String.class, String.class ).newInstance( player.getPlayerID(), player.getPlayerName() );

it does not make sense to use reflection:
Player copyPlayer = new Player( player.getPlayerID(), player.getPlayerName() );

the line
field.set( copyPlayer, field.get( player )); 

is the one that creates your problem, since it assigns to the Hero array of the copyPlayer the array of the original Player, you just need to avoid that field, then:
Player copyPlayer = (Player) clazz.getDeclaredConstructor( String.class, String.class ).newInstance( player.getPlayerID(), player.getPlayerName() );
for( Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields() ) {
   if( !field.getName().equals( "playerID" ) && !field.getName().equals( "playerName" )) {
      field.setAccessible( true );  
      field.set( copyHero, field.get( hero ));  
   }
 }

is replaced by:
Player copyPlayer = new Player();
for( Field field : clazz.getDeclaredFields() ) {
   if( !field.getName().equals( "heros" ) ) {
      field.setAccessible( true );  
      field.set( copyPlayer, field.get( player )); 
   }
   else {
      field.set( copyPlayer, new Vector<>( 2, 1 );;
   }
}

